# Windows Mobile Extension for UWP is not available in VS 2015 Community

Tags: windows-10, win-universal-app

I have installed VS 2015 with Update 1 with custom option where I selected UWP SDK for 10586 and 10240.

[image: VS 2015 Setup]

However, the extension "Windows Mobile Extension for UWP" is not available in the list of extensions in VS 2015.

[image: VS 2015 Project]

Where I can find mentioned extension?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The Windows SDK includes the following Platform extension SDKs: Windows Desktop, **Windows Mobile**, Windows IoT, and Windows Team. When you add these extensions to your Universal Windows app project, device specific APIs and metadata will be made available to your app.

Download the Standalone SDK here: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk

If that doesn't work; try ticking "Emulators for Windows 10 Mobile" on Visual Studio Installation.

Worst case scenario; tick the "Tools and Windows SDK for Winodws 8.1" to see if that might resolve the issue.

Comment: I have been struggling since 2 weeks to get rid of this, I have un-installed vs 2015 and then installed, tried repair but nothing worked for me.